# Update Self join query taking too long to run

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, self-join

I am re-framing my question as below:

I have a query on one table which takes longer than usual to run.There are other inserts/updates queries on the same table but they seem to be running fine.So I am giving the query creating issue as below:

T‌he columns in the table ‌ originally are:

- employeeid
- BusUnitID
- SkillID
- Status
- Severity
- StartDate
- BackgroundStatus

```
alter table fOSMHistory
add RowID int identity,
    FromRowID int,
    LastRowID int,
    LastStatus varchar(10),
    LastSeverity int,ApprLeaveID int;
```

Find the last Colour status before each Blue End Date:

```
Update fOSMHistory
set LastStatus = cs.Status,
    LastSeverity = cs.Severity
from fOSMHistory cs join fOSMHistory ce -- Colour Start and Colour end
    on cs.RowID = ce.LastRowID
join fOSMHistory -- Blue Ends
    on fOSMHistory.Status = 'BlueEnd'
    and cs.employeeid = fOSMHistory.employeeid
    and cs.SkillID = fOSMHistory.SkillID
    and fOSMHistory.StartDate between cs.StartDate and ce.StartDate‌‌
```

The sample data in the table is below:
    ‌‌[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXhXq.jpg)

The columns which are added initially are dropped in the final query and so that is why they are not visible in the final data

Comment: Most likely your query can be re-written without self-join and it would be much faster. Edit the question and add a few dozen rows with sample data, your expected result of the query, format everything nicely and you are likely to get a good answer.

Comment: do you really need the 3rd  instance to join?

Comment: You appear to have indexes on single columns that _include_ other columns. Have you considered an index on _multiple_ columns, e.g. `EmployeeId`, `SkillId` including `StartDate`, `StartDat**e` (?!) on the `fOSMHistory` table?

Comment: Check the query plan.

Comment: Reduce number of conditions on which you joining, stick to ID columns.. The more columns it has to check the slower it will become..